# How to $unwind and include index from original array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am trying the following:

```
db.c1.aggregate([{$unwind: "$arr"}])
```

And this works fine. However, I want to include the index of the array and tried [following the docs like so](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#non-array-field-path):

```
> db.c1.aggregate( [ { $unwind: { path: "$arr", includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex" } } ] )
```

That produces the following error:

```
assert: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: the $unwind field path must be specified as a string",
        "code" : 15981,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: the $unwind field path must be specified as a string",
        "code" : 15981,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:7
2016-04-16T18:37:38.100+0000 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
        "errmsg" : "exception: the $unwind field path must be specified as a string",
        "code" : 15981,
        "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
    at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
    at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
    at (shell):1:7 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

I thought perhaps the problem was `"$arr"` so I substituted in `"arr"` but this results in the same error.

What is wrong in my query? For the record, here's the document I am trying to use:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57127e0475026f0d7a8339c9"), "arr" : [ { "val" : 5, "time" : ISODate("2016-04-16T18:01:40.833Z") }, { "val" : 5, "time" : ISODate("2016-04-16T18:03:52.503Z") }, [ { "val" : 99, "time" : ISODate("2016-04-16T18:04:17.637Z") } ] ] }
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a MongoDB version < 3.2?

Comment: Same happened to me and it was MongoDB version. I was using 3.0.3.